# HTML menu active section illumination

Tags: php, html, css, menu

How do I make the color of a section change in a HTML menu made of DIVs when that section is selected?

Basically, I am creating a menu such as the one on the left of this image:
http://docs.shopify.com/assets/images/manual/orders/orders.jpg?1386029140

How do I make the corresponding section we are on to be "illuminated"?

Do I do it with PHP and having a variable for each div's class?

Comment: Most people do something like class='active' for the element that is selected. If you are on that page, give that element the corresponding class..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably wouldn't be done with PHP, as PHP is server side, JavaScript is more what your looking for as it runs on the clients machine and can be used to respond to clients actions such as mouse clicks.

You can do this with some CSS and Jquery.

First include your Jquery library in your HTML, place this `<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` in the `<head>` tags

Then you can use

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {

      $(this).css.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Where #target is the name of the DIV Id or Class you want to select.